# Undefined variable in view page laravel

Tags: laravel, view, controller

Im getting error in laravel undefined variable all is good but won't know why its coming...
[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM2PR.png)

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuOvz.png)
 [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbbkQ.png)

```
public function login(Request $req)
    {

        $user = users::where([

            ["email", "=", $req->email],
            ["password", "=", $req->password]

        ])->first();

        if (isset($user)) {

            $req->session()->put("log", $req->input());

            return redirect("/userlist");
        } else {
            $b="user not found";

            return view("login", compact("b"));
        }
```

Comment: Welcome. What is your question? Have you followed the advice given in the error message?

Comment: Please don't paste your code as images, we can't help you like it. Include your code in question.

Comment: Post your code please, not only image. We can't help you with this little information

Comment: check know @kerbholz

Comment: check know @zlatan

Comment: it seems when the login page initially loads the `b` variable is undefined and you are getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may fix it by defining `$b` variable inside your controller method

```
public function myLoginFunction() {
//...
$b = ...;
return view('viewName', ['b' => $b]);
}
```

**Edit**

```
public function login(Request $req) {

    $user = users::where([

        ["email", "=", $req->email],
        ["password", "=", $req->password]

    ])->first();

    if (isset($user)) {

        $req->session()->put("log", $req->input());

        return redirect("/userlist");
    } else {

        return view("login");
    }
}
```

App\Providers\AppServiceProvider

```
//...
public function boot()
{

    View::composer('login', function ($view) {
        $view->with('b', "user not found");
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but see my code i already defined variable in my controller

Comment: Could you plz add your controller code ?

Comment: Yeah see @Foued MOUSSI

Comment: @ShahrukhAliLodhi check updated answer

Comment: thanks brother  its help me @Foued MOUSSI

Answer (score 0):

make sure pass varibale to the view from your controller

**example**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return View
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        return view('user.profile', ['user' => User::findOrFail($id)]);
    }
}
```

please see [laravel controllers documnet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers)